# How to insert all questions in one form?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Got 3 tables :

1. Question (QuestionId,QuestionText)
2. Survey(SurveyId,QuestionId,UserId,AnswerTExt,Comment)
3. User(UserId,UserName)

How to make a form in a view  for all questions in table question .

Example I got 90 questions , when I answer this form 5 times , Table answers must have 450 records

Controller:

```
public class SurveysController : Controller
{
    private TESTEntities db = new TESTEntities();

    // GET: Surveys
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var surveys = db.Surveys.Include(s => s.Question).Include(s => s.User);
        return View(surveys.ToList());
    }

    // GET: Surveys/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Survey survey = db.Surveys.Find(id);
        if (survey == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(survey);
    }

    // GET: Surveys/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
       ViewBag.QuestionId = new SelectList(db.Questions, "QuesionId", "QuestionText");
        ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(db.Users, "UserId", "Name");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Surveys/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "SuerveyId,UserId,QuestionId,Answer,Comment")] Survey survey)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Surveys.Add(survey);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.QuestionId = new SelectList(db.Questions, "QuesionId", "QuestionText", survey.QuestionId);
        ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(db.Users, "UserId", "Name", survey.UserId);
        return View(survey);
    }

    // GET: Surveys/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Survey survey = db.Surveys.Find(id);
        if (survey == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.QuestionId = new SelectList(db.Questions, "QuesionId", "QuestionText", survey.QuestionId);
        ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(db.Users, "UserId", "Name", survey.UserId);
        return View(survey);
    }

    // POST: Surveys/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "SuerveyId,UserId,QuestionId,Answer,Comment")] Survey survey)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(survey).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.QuestionId = new SelectList(db.Questions, "QuesionId", "QuestionText", survey.QuestionId);
        ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(db.Users, "UserId", "Name", survey.UserId);
        return View(survey);
    }

    // GET: Surveys/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Survey survey = db.Surveys.Find(id);
        if (survey == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(survey);
    }

    // POST: Surveys/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Survey survey = db.Surveys.Find(id);
        db.Surveys.Remove(survey);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Create View:

```
@model TEST.Models.Survey

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Survey</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserId, "UserId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("UserId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.QuestionId)
        {
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QuestionId, "QuestionId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.HiddenFor(s=>s.QuestionId)
                @Html.ValueFor(s =>item)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Answer, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Answer, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Answer, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comment, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comment, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comment, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        }

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is when i want to create , it creates the number of fields for each question , but doesnt show the question , and it doesnt submit

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/u3ag9fzb7/ here

Comment: I don't understand why you're passing questions & users in selectlists.

Comment: Entity framework generated this , from ado.net model , should i change in something else ?

Comment: Entity Framework generated this? `ViewBag.QuestionId = new SelectList(db.Questions, "QuesionId", "QuestionText");`

Comment: Yes. I used ADO.Net model from my ms sql server , then added through entity framework controllers and views(All types)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I want to make sure I understand what you are trying to do.

In your Create action you are getting all the Questions from the Question table and adding them to the View bag as QuestionId.

Assuming that when you debug the code, you see the correct data in Viewbag.QuestionId when you try to print your label to the screen with

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.QuestionId, "QuestionId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

You are trying to print out the object of QuestionId. I think you need to use 'item' in your label because this changes as your code iterates through the collection.

```
item.Question
```

should be used where you want to print out the text of the question